# ListView showing wrong text VB6.0

Tags: listview, unicode, vb6, codepages

I've been testing an application using a listView which works well with Western European Characters. However if the locale is in Turkish the characters appear to be wrong in the listview.

For example the character 'Ş' will appear as 'Þ'.

I can see that both characters are represented as decimal: 254.

How can I force my listView to use the local codepage rather than unicode?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't use unicode if it's in a VB form package.

VB6 is an ANSI app (Win95 didn't have an unicode API). Unicode internally and when using COM. But creating a Window, which a listbox is, uses ANSI.

Therefore you need to set the nonunicode codepage in Regional Settings.

Also Help has a whole chapter on this.

Answer (score 0):

turns out you can set the listview's charset outlined below:

```
listView.Font.Charset = 1 ' Default charset obtains current codepage
```

This has resolved my issue although language format needs to be the same as Locale.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things the MSHFlexGrid offers is Unicode support.  There is no "Unicode problem" in VB6 at all, it's an issue of choosing the right controls.

If there had ever been an evolution beyond VB6 we'd have seen more controls moved to Unicode as Win9x died away.  Sadly this was cut short.

If you need a Unicode ListView there *are* things you could do.  There are 3rd party controls or even approaches that can burrow underneath the ListView control wrapper in the OCX using Unicode subclassing.